# Update query on QGIS 2.14.13

Tags: qgis, update-query

I am currently using QGIS and it's database tool with custom plugins. I have to update a specific Table using an SQL query but I cannot use Database specific programs like PostGIS. Here is the test query I used:

```
UPDATE  "BAL"
SET
"BAL"."BAL_ADRESSE" = "BAL2"."bal_adresse"
FROM "BAL", "BAL2"
WHERE "BAL"."BAL_ADRESSE" != "BAL2"."bal_adresse";
```

It is quite a simple query, I am trying to replace values in the first BAL table using a csv I created myself and imported in the same database afterwards, calling it BAL2. Yet everytime I try to do anything than basic selections, like the update I need to do, it returns an error message and never the same.

So here are my questions: Is my query wrong? And is QGIS unable to use the UPDATE query?

Comment: We need an exact error message, but you appear to have syntax errors all over the place. Joining on a not-equals is going to cause polynomial expansion.

Comment: The previous version was like this:

`UPDATE TABLE "BAL"
SET
"BAL"."BAL_ADRESSE" = "BAL2"."bal_adresse"
FROM "BAL", "BAL2"
WHERE "BAL2"."bal_pk_uid" = "BAL"."BAL_PK_UID";`

And it wasn't working any better. It always gices me back a synthax error near table or near the first dot.

Comment: 1) never use uppercase table or column names, 2) consult documentation for proper UPDATE syntax, 3) There is no GIS component to this question, so this would be better asked in [dba.se]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it worked after tinkering with it for almost an hour i found out this worked as intended:

```
UPDATE "BAL"
SET
"BAL_ADRESSE" = (Select "BAL2"."bal_adress"
FROM  "BAL2"
WHERE "BAL2"."bal_pk_uid" = "BAL"."BAL_PK_UID");
```

Comment: That should produce an error as well -- BAL3 is undefined.

Comment: Oops, edited: It was BAL not BAL 3